# Error when deleting Role, User or Tenant

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

ABP version: 3.2.4

I'm new at this template and just playing with the framework. I have a fresh Angular and ASP.NET Core app, but I cannot delete a role, user or tenant. In Firefox, I see this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (scripts.bundle.js:12844)
at Function.e.Deferred (scripts.bundle.js:219)
at Object.abp.message.confirm (scripts.bundle.js:12843)
at RolesComponent.delete (webpack-
internal:///../../../../../src/app/roles/roles.component.ts:55)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent]
(ng:///AppModule/RolesComponent.ngfactory.js:52)
at handleEvent (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:13450)
at callWithDebugContext (webpack-
internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14935)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (webpack-
internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:14522)
at dispatchEvent (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:9899)
at eval (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:10513)
View_RolesComponent_2 @ ng:///AppModule/RolesComponent.ngfactory.js:47
```

This is my config in **package.json**:

```
"sweetalert": "^1.1.3"
"abp-ng2-module": "^1.3.0"
"abp-web-resources": "^3.2.2"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, this seems to be related to sweetalert. Can you check the versions of sweetalert and abp-web-resources packages in package.json ?

Comment: Hi ismcagdas. Thanks for reply, I have edited my question with informations from package.json. It is just a fresh template from aspnetboilerplate, without any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the recent abp version sweet alert throws exception if it's being triggered two times. So you might fall into this case. Deleting a user shows confirmations dialog with sweet alert. If there's a problem on the server side a new sweet alert is being shown. so what you have to do is update the sweet alert to the latest. 
see https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/2694

Comment: Sorry I cant because I am new here?!?!

Comment: @HrvojeJursetic You can click on the check mark on the left of the answer.